# Can arrow functions be used in ES6 class defenitions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can arrow functions technically be used in ES6 class definitions?  I am not asked if they should be, but if they can be?

I was curious after reading his [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) said they were `ill suited as methods`.

If so what is the proper syntax?

```
class someComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   }

  // arrow function here

  render () {
  }
}
```

**Research**

[Currying with Arrow Functions](https://medium.com/@harouny/currying-in-javascript-arrow-function-sequence-2a510441215a)

Comment: From what I know, the 'ill suited' part is because they have some oddities (so to speak) like the 'this' keyword (creates its own binding) that can make you hit a lot of undefined because it will go up to the parent of the parent of the parent etc

Comment: Is it just the parent, or ( the parent of the parent ... etc. ).

Comment: off the top of my head, it will start searching for 'this' as far back as it goes until it reaches the window (I think again). I know for sure it starts going up the tree basically and you usually hit the error 'cannot use this of undefined'. It basically looks for somewhere that you've already defined the word 'this'.

Comment: In short, the answer to your question is "Yes", they can be. It is quite common in the example you provide to use them to avoid having to bind `this` to event handlers in the constructor.

Comment: @Ted - Are you referring to event handlers in the constructor are calling object methods directly or referencing them? `onClick = myMethod();` or `onClick = myMethod;`

Comment: @Ted Only if you use the experimental class-properties transform from Babel.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding there is not a proper syntax because an arrow function does not provide any benefit. However, if you were wondering how you might include an arrow function inside your class well... Here you go:

```js
class someClass {
  constructor() {
    this.myTestProperty = "fus ro dah";
    this.someArrowMethod = () => {
      console.log("Arrow Method: ", this.myTestProperty);
    };
  }

  method() {
    console.log("Normal Method: ", this.myTestProperty);
  }

  //ERROR: this is illegal in node v10 but webpack or typescript may be able to compile it correctly. 
  illegalArrowMethod = () => {

  }
}

const something = new someClass();

something.method();
something.someArrowMethod();
```

As you can see the correct class Object's properties are still available via the `this` keyword inside the normal Method. So I can't think of a use case why you would use an arrow function inside your class.

Comment: *an arrow function does not provide any benefit* -- 

Oh it does. I saves many lines of `this.foo = this.foo.bind( this )` in the constructor, and it's a proposal which can be transpiled using Babel with `babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties`. I add this by default to my projects so I don't have to write the binding boilerplate over and over.

Comment: *I can't think of a use case why you would use an arrow function inside your class.*  -- In a React class component: `handleChange(e){ this.setState({ val : e.target.value })` vs `handleChange = e => { this.setState({ val : e.target.value })`, then `<input onChange={ this.handleChange } />`. The former requires you to write `this.handleChange.bind( this )` either in the constructor, on in the render method; the latter just works as expected.

Comment: @Pawl you're right arrow functions are fantastic and preferred in most cases. And I'm aware React has some syntax troubles regarding `this` within components. But this question was specifically directed at ES6 classes. Methods defined in plain javascript do have access to `this` without having to bind it as shown in my example.

Comment: I agree it is more prominent in React when dealing with event handlers, but it's not inherent to "React having syntax troubles", it's just the nature of JS and its scoping. Here's an example of non-React JS class with a simple value increment using `setInterval` and the scoping issues kick in: https://jsfiddle.net/ma0kdpxu/

Comment: I suppose that is a valid use case. I think if you were working outside of React I would prefer something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Mikkal24/qw5va7rh/3/

Maybe the arrow method will someday gain support it some future version of javascript but, for now the only way it works is if it's defined in constructor or if you use babel.